No shaded.jar file is actually created when running mvn clean package on a Java/Maven project with shade plugin
I'm making a simple weather app with JavaFX/Jackson libraries and Maven. When I run mvn clean package the regular -1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is created in the target directory and it says that the -1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar is copied over it. However when I go in file explorer or use the dir command in the target folder, no -shaded.jar file actually exists and its just the -1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and original-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar that are there. When I try to run the -1.0-SHNAPSHOT.jar it says "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application". The application runs fine from within Intelij.
I've tried troubleshooting with different online recourses (mostly chat) to diagnose an issue. I've tried adding/removing a bunch of different things from the pom, mostly to do with the shade plugin. I've reviewed the javaFX parts and versions I'm using and I can't spot any issues. Again it runs without issue in Intelij so I'm not sure what javaFx components could be missing.
